# How to aggregate on a foreign key and a specific field at the same time?

Tags: django

My table named Value has a one to many relationship with the table Country and the table Output_outcome_impact. I have a query that is working fine and gets what I want but then I need to do an average of the value field, but this average needs to be done for each unique id_output_outcome_impact and not the whole query.

```
class Country(models.Model):
    country_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, primary_key=True)
    CONTINENTCHOICE = (
    ('Africa', 'Africa'),
    ('America', 'America'),
    ('Asia', 'Asia'),
    ('Europe', 'Europe'),
    ('Oceania', 'Oceania')
    )
    region = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    continent = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=CONTINENTCHOICE)
    GDP_per_capita = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    unemployment_rate = models.FloatField(null=True)
    female_unemployment_rate = models.FloatField(null=True)
    litteracy_rate = models.FloatField(null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.country_name



class OutputOutcomeImpact(models.Model):
    output_outcome_impact_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, primary_key=True)
    TYPECHOICE = (
    ('Output', 'Output'),
    ('Outcome', 'Outcome'),
    ('Impact', 'Impact'),
    )
    type = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=TYPECHOICE)
    description = models.TextField()
    TARGETGROUP = (
    ('Standard', 'Standard'),
    ('Investors', 'Investors'),
    ('Local authorities and NGOs', 'Local authorities and NGOs'),
    )
    target_group = models.CharField(max_length=255,choices=TARGETGROUP)
    question = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    parent_name = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True, blank=True)
    indicator = models.ForeignKey(Indicator, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.output_outcome_impact_name

class Activity(models.Model):
    activity_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, primary_key=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    product_service = models.TextField()
    output_outcome = models.TextField()
    outcome_impact = models.TextField()
    output_outcome_impacts = models.ManyToManyField('OutputOutcomeImpact')
    countries = models.ManyToManyField('Country')
    sectors = models.ManyToManyField('Sector')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.activity_name


class Value(models.Model):
    value_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, primary_key=True)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    id_output_outcome_impact = models.ForeignKey(OutputOutcomeImpact, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    value_has_source = models.ManyToManyField('Source')
    value = models.FloatField()
    function_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default = "multiply")
    def __str__(self):
        return self.value_name

region_values = Value.objects.filter(id_output_outcome_impact__output_outcome_impact_name__in = output_pks, country_id__region = region).exclude(country_id__country_name = country).values()
```

So the result of the query is available below, and what I would like to achieve is to set the value field to an average of every object that has the same id_output_outcome_impact_id, here Dioxins and furans emissions reduction appears twice so I would like to get the 2 values set as their average.

```
<QuerySet [{'value_name': 'Waste_to_dioxins', 'country_id': 'Malawi', 'id_output_outcome_impact_id': 'Dioxins and furans emissions reduction', 'value': 0.0003, 'function_name': 'multiply'}, {'value_name': 'Waste_to_dioxins_south_africa', 'country_id': 'South Africa', 'id_output_outcome_impact_id': 'Dioxins and furans emissions reduction', 'value': 150.0, 'function_name': 'multiply'}, {'value_name': 'Households getting electricity per kWh', 'country_id': 'Malawi', 'id_output_outcome_impact_id': 'Households that get electricity', 'value': 0.0012, 'function_name': 'multiply'}, {'value_name': 'Dioxin to disease', 'country_id': 'Malawi', 'id_output_outcome_impact_id': 'Reduction of air pollution related diseases', 'value': 0.31, 'function_name': 'multiply'}]>
```

I am wondering if django models allow such modification (I went through the doc and saw the annotate function with the average but couldn't make it work for my specific case), that would be nice. Thanks.

Comment: Here's quite a good article that I think covers what you want: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/12/06/how-to-create-group-by-queries.html

Comment: Yes, it was what I was looking for, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
region_values = Value.objects.filter(id_output_outcome_impact__output_outcome_impact_name__in = output_pks, country_id__region = region).exclude(country_id__country_name = country).values('id_output_outcome_impact__output_outcome_impact_name').annotate(Avg('value'))
```